# Executable exiting preemptively when ranging over an empty channel

Tags: go, concurrency, range, channel

I recently encountered a coding exercise which I solved in python in which I had to port an "algorithm". I don't know how it is called which is why I am describing it:
Each new line was a description of the previous line by the amount of the same number printed in sequence and the associated number.
Here is an example:

```
1
11
21
1211
111221
312211
etc
```

I started learning Go with its channels and concurrency features. So I came back to this exercise to try to solve it more efficiently in parallel with Go.
This is what I got so far:

```
package main

func main() {
    channel := make(chan uint8)
    go treeCalcRoutine(channel, 0)
    channel <- 1
    close(channel) //defer is not an option in this case because the channel has 
    //to be closed before main exits
}

func treeCalcRoutine(in <-chan uint8, generation int) {
    if generation > 10 {
        return // return after 10 recursive iterations
    }
    out := make(chan uint8)
    defer close(out)
    num := uint8(1)
    previous := <-i
    go treeCalcRoutine(out, generation+1)
    for val := range in {
        switch {
        case val == previous:
            num++
        default:
            num = uint8(1)
            out <- num
            out <- val
        }
        previous = val
    }
    out <- num
    out <- previous
}
```

While trying to debug the program using [Delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/), I figured out the Program quits without an exception (and exit status 0) while trying to range over an empty/closed channel. I expected the program just to skip the for loop altogether in this case.
I still want to solve this challenge myself so I would appreciate if someone could just point me in the right direction instead of producing a functioning solution. Moreover, please point out any other issues/cases which could be done better (like the `generation` limit).

EDIT:
Since people asking me to post the error: There is no error at all for some reason. The program just exits once it reaches the for loop.

Comment: Please post the actual error and the line triggering it. There is no error for "ranging over an empty channel" - it just waits until there is something to receive.

Comment: Why could `close(channel)` as the last statement in `main` do anything? I think you have some fundamental misunderstanding about channels.

Comment: @JimB As far as i know, the `for range` loop would never stop looping unless the channel gets closed.

Comment: @Swiftb0y no that's not it. Closing channel will close the channel in that case you cannot send more value on the channel if it is closed, compiler will throw an error saying cannot send value on closed channel.

Comment: @Himanshu yes, it does that primarily but as https://gobyexample.com/range-over-channels suggests it will terminate the for loop as well.

Comment: @Swiftb0y: closing the channel will cause a for range loop to exit, but at the end of `main` the program is exiting, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Swiftb0y yes it does will close the for loop. But better is to check if there is a value in the channel using switch with `ok`. If it has then flush it on the receiver end. But even if you do not close the channel if does not effect your code. One more thing where are you printing your values in the function to check if your code is going correct.

Comment: It still doesn't matter. Closing at the end of `main` is superfluous. When `main` returns, the program exits. No channels/goroutines/anything else will survive.

Comment: Ohhh I think I know what the issue is: The Program is quiting because once the for loop is done, the main routine is done as well and it will kill all the other goroutines as well. So really the question is how I can prevent the main routine from exiting until the first if clause evaluates to true. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: @Himanshu The compiler does not detect send on a closed channel.  Perhaps you meant to say that send on a closed channel panics.

Comment: @Swiftb0y somehow the assumption is not upto the mark because the go routine will run on a thread. Main will exit because it is not waiting for the go routine to finish

Comment: @ThunderCat yes I mean to say that it will panic if we try to send on a closed channel.

Comment: Ok. I understand the issue now. But how can I prevent the main routine from exiting until the routines finished?

Comment: @Swiftb0y use `wait groups` it will wait for all the go routines to finish.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was not actually that the for loop was exiting when it was encountering the closed channel but the main routine exited at that exact time which caused every other goroutine to terminate as well. I was advised to use waitgroups in this case.